# Issue on horizontal scrolling text with delay and appearance

Tags: html, css, transform

When I add animation-delay on the second text, the first one appears without moving. And I don't succeed to have an infinite loop of the text scrolling. There is always some breaking point when the animation is over.

I tried several codes that I found online, but none of them did exactly what I wanted to do.

```css
.scroll span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 92vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.second span {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="scroll first"><span>scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down </span></p>
  <p class="scroll second"><span>scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down </span></p>
</div>
```

I just want an infinite scrolling text.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have a delay in your second animation is because you have the animation set to go from -100% to 100%, which is essentially 2 animation cycles. As a result, there is a whitespace break in your animation for approximately 1 cycle. Think about it as the text moving in a circle. From -100% to 0, the text is moving on the screen, but from 0 to 100%, the text is off the screen circling back to the starting point. Your animation should be from -100% to 0.

You also need to add `display: inline-block` and `padding-left: 100%` to `.scroll span` to keep the 2 `span` tags side by side.

```css
.scroll {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 92vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
}

.second span {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="scroll">
    <span>scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down&nbsp;</span>
  </p>
  <p class="scroll second">
    <span> scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down scroll down&nbsp;</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you man that's perfect! But there is one little issue, there is no blank between the first p and the second. We can notice that on the "scroll downscroll down". What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Good catch! I've edited that in for you. Just add `&nbsp;` to the end of both spans to break the texts up. Make sure there is **NO** space before the `&nbsp;` or it will register *2* spaces. It should be like this: `down&nbsp;</span>`

Comment: Everything works fine on codepen, but when I import everything on my project, despite the `overflow: hidden`, my text takes more than the viewwidth so it destroys my website, what can I do? Also, there is too much space between the first and the second `p`, should I reduce the delay?

Comment: I fixed the overflow issue with just a `width: 100vw`, but I still have some issue with the white space